# how to get the exact path of a file to convert it binary?http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=11_logcat.png

Tags: android

After lots of search i found the full path of the file but while converting it into binary FileNotFoundException' occurred Please Help Guys.

my Codes are

1.

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /*
             * Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setType("/*");
             * intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             * startActivityForResult(intent, 33);
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            // Set your required file type
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "DEMO"),
                    1001);

        }
    });
```

2.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String displayName = null;

     byte[] bytes = null;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the Uri of the selected file
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String uriString = uri.toString();
        File myFile = new File(uriString);
        String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                        null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = myFile.getName();

        }

         String Str = new String(path);

         int endPortal=Str.indexOf("document/"); 
         String fullpath=Str.substring(0,endPortal)+"document/"+displayName;

                 try {

         bytes=CommonHelper.getGalleryDetails(fullpath); } catch
         (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace(); } Log.e("fileBinary:", bytes.toString());


         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Binary" + bytes.toString(), 5000).show();
```

}
}

//I am Getting error on FilePath
//CommonHelper class where getGalleryDetails are written

3.

```
public static byte[] getGalleryDetails(String FilePath)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

bytes = output.toByteArray();
```

Log.e("byte", bytes.toString());
output = null;

```
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Please see the above logcate link in title please help me ...thanks in advance

Comment: What is `fullpath` exactly in `bytes=CommonHelper.getGalleryDetails(fullpath); }` ?

Comment: `I am Getting error on FilePath`. Which error. Pleqase show the logcat.

Comment: i have uploaded the  logcat please see greenapps

Comment: `After lots of search i found the full path of the file `. Which file? Could you please start with explaining what this code shoul do or the user does?

Comment: You still  did not tell what the full path was. And  you did not tell which error you got. And you did not post the logcat.